# Get value from datareader

Tags: vb.net, datareader

Given below is a sample piece of code I've written in VB.NET.

```
 commandReader.CommandText = "Select stu_id from tbl_students Where stu_id = 845)"
   dr = commandReader.ExecuteReader
   While dr.Read
        var_stu_id = dr!stu_id
        var_stu_id = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("stu_id"))
        var_stu_id = dr("stu_id")
        var_stu_id = dr.GetValue("stu_id")
   End While
   dr.Close()
```

There are 4 ways of getting a particular value from a `DataReader`. I would like to know which is the best method among them(if anyone point out the difference between each of them then it'll be a great help).

Comment: `dr("stu_id")` is the most common. As you noted, VB does have the ! operator for dereferencing collections and it's been around forever. It is just a syntactic shortcut to the third option. If you're super-curious, download the Ref12 extension and select Go To Definition on the particular method call. It will show you the .NET source used to write it. For instance, it's possible that dr.Item("stu_id") (same as dr("stu_id") will resolve to the same or very similar code as dr.GetValue("stu_id").

Comment: This has nothing to do with c#.

Answer (score 1):

`var_stu_id = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("stu_id"))`

Is the best method to Retrieve data from DataReader.

1. `Get<Datatype>` functions used to retrieve specific DataType values from DataReader. But `GetValue()` can be used to retrieve any data type value.
2. `GetOrdinal()` accepts **index no** of the column as well as **Column Name** as column reference which is a advantage of using this method from my point of view.
3. I tried other methods before and By far this is the best method for me to retrieve data from DataReader. Other Method gave some exceptions like `NullReferenceException` while accessing columns.

Answer (score 0):

The DataReader provides a series of methods that allow you to access column values in their native data types (`GetDateTime`, `GetDouble`, `GetGuid`, `GetInt32`, and so on).**Using the typed accessor methods, assuming the underlying data type is known, reduces the amount of type conversion required when retrieving the column value.**

Out of the 4 ways you have shown,the best method is `var_stu_id = dr.GetValue("stu_id")`.
Because **it Gets the value of the specified column in its native format**.

Source: [sqldatareader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)

[data from datareader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)